# Why does this LOOKUP even work and how does it work?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula and it gives 1080. When I highlight B1:B3 (which contain 0, 1, 0) and press F9, it gives this array: {0;1;0}. So, I replace the B1:B3 with {0;1;0} and, now, the formula gives #N/A. This leads to my question: what does F9 really give? From what I can see, B1:B3 and {0,1,0} are equivalent but the formula doesn't think so.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(ROW(INDIRECT("1:2880")),{1;421;961;1441;1861;2401;2881;2881;2881;2881},B1:B3))
```

Excel 2010

This is just one example. I have been getting same phenomena on different array formulae quite often lately. When cell addresses are replaced by manually entered arrays, the formula no longer works. This happens to some, but not all, formulae. In simple INDEX or OFFSET, manually entered arrays can replace cell addresses and the formula/function still works.

Here is the screenshots. The first one is the original formula. If I highlight B1:B3 and hit F9, the array, {0,1,0}, appears. If I highlight the first, hence, the original, formula and hit F9, I get 1080. If I highlight B1:B3 to get the array and then highlight the entire formula then hit F9, I got #N/A.

[image]

NOTE: further investigation shows that if the array is expanded to be the same size as the array before it, the formula will work. Instead of using {0;1;0}, I use {0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} and the formula gives 540. This is the expected result. So, now, the question becomes why would B1:B3 work and how does it work? The title has been updated to reflect the new question.

Comment: can you share some screenshot?

Comment: p._phidot_ I have edited the post and added few screenshots in one picture.

Comment: What is in B1, B2, B3? The screenshot shows F6. How does that relate to the question?

Comment: B1, B2, B3 are 0, 1, 0. That is why when I highlight B1:B3 and hit F9, the array {0;1;0} replaces B1:B3. F6 is where the formula resides.

Comment: With the newly found insight, I have changed the title.

Comment: does `=LOOKUP(2880,{1;421;961;1441;1861;2401;2881;2881;2881;2881},B1:B10)` (no ctrl-shift-enter, just enter) gives the same result?

Comment: No. It doesn't give an array. It gives 0. I think the first argument needs to be an array.

Comment: since the in put is {0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}, why do we get 540 from the defined {1;421;961;1441;1861;2401;2881;2881;2881;2881} array ? (as of I can understand.. it should gives 421.)

Comment: ROW(INDIRECT("1:2880") gives and array of 1 to 2880. From 1 to 420, LOOKUP gives 0; from 421 to 960, LOOKUP gives 1; above 960, LOOKUP gives 0. when summing up, you get 540.